How to sort 2D array from horizontal (left-to-right) to vertical (top-to-bottom)
I want to convert the 2d array which is missing some values and has been sorted from left to right to a new array which is sorted from top to bottom like below examples. Cols and rows and the number of items in the array are dynamic, can be changed to any number. Thank you!

When cols = 3, rows = 3
Input:

0 | 1 | 2
3 | 4 | 5
6

Expected:
0 | 3 | 5
1 | 4 | 6
2 | 


When cols = 5, rows = 2

Input:
0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4
5 | 6

Expected:
0 | 2 | 4 | 5 | 6
1 | 3

UPDATE with code JavaScript code
const input = [[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6]];
const expected = convert(input);
// expected = [[0, 3, 5], [1, 4, 6], [2]];

const input = [[0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6]];
const expected = convert(input);
// expected = [[0, 2, 4, 5, 6], [1, 3]];

UPDATE 2
I have tried this way:
const input = [[0,1,2],
               [3,4,5],
               [6]];

const array = flatToArray(input);
console.log("--- Array:---");
console.log(array);

const rows = input.length;
const cols = input[0].length;

const result = [];
for (let i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
    result[i] = [];
    for (let j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
        result[i].push(array[i%rows + j*rows]);
    }
}

function flatToArray(input) {
    return input.reduce((prev, current) => prev.concat(current), []);
}
 
console.log("--- Final:---");
console.log(result)

Output:
--- Array:---
[
  0, 1, 2, 3,
  4, 5, 6
]
--- Final:---
[ [ 0, 3, 6 ], [ 1, 4, undefined ], [ 2, 5, undefined ] ]


Are all the "missing values" in the last row? Do all rows have the same number of elements, except the last row, which can have fewer?

Are you looking for help in Java or Javascript?

@OldDogProgrammer Are you looking for help in Java or Javascript? Either is fine.

@OldDogProgrammer Are all the "missing values" in the last row? Yes, only the last row has fewer values. Other rows will have full elements.

please be aware of https://javascriptisnotjava.com/ - it is even in the tooltip of the [tag:javascript] tag: "Note that JavaScript is NOT Java."

You should edit the question to include the answer to the "missing values" question.

If this is of any importance to you, can you provide feedback on the answers to your question?

General Logic
Here is an attempt using the selection sort logic for a generic Comparable type.
At the beginning, it's retrieved the largest sub-array's size to iterate through the columns first, and then for each column iterate through its rows. At each iteration, it's first made sure that the current j-th column is present for the i-th sub-array. Then, the method looks for a smaller element among the following ones, and when it's found, the smaller value is swapped with the current one.
Demo
Here is a demo at OneCompiler with your 2 test cases.
Java Implementation
public static <T extends Comparable<T>> void vertSort(T[][] mat) {
    //Retrieving the size of the largest sub-array
    int maxCol = Arrays.stream(mat).mapToInt(v -> v.length).max().orElse(0);
    T temp;

    //Iterating the columns first, and then for each column iterating its rows
    for (int j = 0; j < maxCol; j++) {
        for (int i = 0; i < mat.length; i++) {

            //Skipping the j-th column if this is not present for the current sub-array
            if (j >= mat[i].length) {
                continue;
            }

            //Iterating the columns first, and then for each column iterating its rows
            for (int j2 = j; j2 < maxCol; j2++) {

                //Selection sort approach where i2 is initialized to the next element if we're still on the same column
                //or to 0 if we've moved forward
                for (int i2 = j2 == j ? i + 1 : 0; i2 < mat.length; i2++) {

                    //Skipping the j2-th column if this is not present for the current sub-array
                    if (j2 >= mat[i2].length) {
                        continue;
                    }

                    //If a following element is smaller than the current one than they're swapped
                    if (mat[i2][j2].compareTo(mat[i][j]) < 0) {
                        temp = mat[i][j];
                        mat[i][j] = mat[i2][j2];
                        mat[i2][j2] = temp;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


The way I see this... JavaScript
function convert( arr2D )
  {
  let 
    xIn = arr2D.flat()
  , xRP = arr2D.reduce((a,x,i)=>(a.R[i]=[],x.forEach((_,j)=>a.P.push({i,j})),a),{R:[],P:[]})
    ;
  xRP.P
    .sort((a,b)=>(a.j-b.j)||(a.i-b.i))
    .forEach(({i,j})=>xRP.R[i][j]=xIn.shift())
    ;
  return xRP.R
  }


Test code (with comments)


// testing...

test_convert( [[0,1,2],[3,4,5],[6]], [[0,3,5],[1,4,6],[2]] );
test_convert( [[0,1,2,3,4],[5,6]],   [[0,2,4,5,6],[1,3]]   );
test_convert( [[0,1,2,3,4],[5,6],[7,8,9]], [[0,3,6,8,9],[1,4],[2,5,7]] );


//----------- testing function -----------

function test_convert( arrIn, expArr )
  {
  let
    sIn  = JSON.stringify( arrIn )
  , sOut = JSON.stringify( convert( arrIn ) )
  , sExp = JSON.stringify( expArr )
  , isOK = sOut === sExp
    ;
  console.log(
    'in:\n', sIn.replaceAll('],[',']\n ,['), '\n',
    'out: ', (isOK ? '== conform' : '!= not conform as expected'),'\n',
    sOut.replaceAll('],[',']\n ,['),
    '\n' );
  }
/* snippet makeUp */
.as-console-wrapper { max-height:100% !important; top:0; left:0 !important; width:100%; }
.as-console-row{ background-color: lemonchiffon; }
.as-console-row::after{ display:none !important; }
.as-console-row-code{ font-size: 16px !important;  }
<script>

function convert( arr2D )
  {
  const 
    xIn = arr2D.flat()  // make an array of continious elements to set at thier new place
  , xRP = arr2D.reduce((a,x,i)=>  // acc, arr, indx
      ( a.R[i] = []              // make array squeleton
      , x.forEach((_,j)=>   
          a.P.push( {i,j} )   // coords, == list order in xIn
        )
      , a                   // return value for reduce loop
      )
      ,{R:[],P:[]})       // initials values of `a` on reduce loop
    ;
  xRP.P
    .sort((a,b)=>(a.j-b.j)||(a.i-b.i))             // sort coords on j, i
    .forEach( ({i,j})=>xRP.R[i][j] = xIn.shift())  // replace elemnts in new order
    ;
  return xRP.R  // that's the result
  }


</script>




Since the source array is already sorted, there is no need to resort it.
One way to handle this is to copy the elements of the source (input) array to an intermediate 1-D array, and then fill the destination (output) array from the intermediate array. But, if a multi-dimensional array is regular, it is easy to treat it as a 1-D array without actually moving the elements.
For a 2-D array, to calculate the row and column of the pth element, the math would look something like this:
int[][] arr = new int [numRows][numColumns]; 
// 
// which row and column index is element #p ?
int row = p / numColumns;
int column = p % numColmns; 
int element = arr[row][column];

In addition, given a row and column, the single dimension index can be calculated.
So, one could conceivably move an entire multi-dimensional array without using a single loop.
But, in the question, the arrays are almost, but not entirely regular.
Here is one solution:
   
/* utility method to output 2-D array of int so each row is on one line */
public static void print2D (PrintStream out, int [][] arr) {
     for (int i = 0;  i < arr.length; ++i) {
        out.println (Arrays.toString (arr[i]));   
     }
 }
    

 public static void testMoveRowColumns () {
     int [][][] test = {   {{0,1,2}, {3,4,5}, {6}}
                         , {{1,2,3,4},{5,6}}
                         , {{11,12,13,14,15}, {}}
                         , { {101,102,103,104,105,106,107}
                            ,{108,109,110,111,112,113,114}
                            ,{115,116,117,118,119,120,121}
                            ,{122,123,124,125,126,127,128}
                            ,{129,130,131}
                        }
                         , {{21,22,23,24},{25,26,27,28},{29,30,31,32}}
                       };
     PrintStream out = System.out;
     for (int i = 0; i < test.length; ++i) {          
          int [][] result = moveRowColumns (test[i]);  
          out.println ("\nInput:");
          print2D (out,test[i]);
          out.println ("\nOutput:");
          print2D (out,result);                          
     }
 }
    
 public static int[][] moveRowColumns(int[][] source) {
     int numColumns = source[0].length;
     int numFullRows = source.length - 1;
     int lengthLastRow = source[source.length - 1].length;

     int[][] destination = new int[numFullRows + 1][numColumns];
     destination[source.length - 1] = new int[lengthLastRow];

     int sourceIndex = -1;
     column:
     for (int destColumn = 0; destColumn < numColumns; ++destColumn) {
         for (int destRow = 0; destRow < source.length; ++destRow) {
             if (destRow >= numFullRows && destColumn >= lengthLastRow) {
                 continue column;
             }
             ++sourceIndex;
             int sourceRow = sourceIndex / numColumns;
             int sourceColumn = sourceIndex % numColumns;
             destination [destRow][destColumn]
                = source[sourceRow][sourceColumn];
         }
     }

     return destination;
 }

This approach goes column-by-column. Filling each column starts with the top row, and goes down. When the last row is reached, it is either filled or the outer loop is jumped to the next column.
For indexing the source array, the row and column indices are calculated given the sequential (1-D) element index.
Notes:

Code in this answer is in Java
About the creation of array with last row possibly shorter:

int[][] destination = new int[numFullRows + 1][numColumns];
destination[source.length - 1] = new int[lengthLastRow];

The 2nd line in the above segment throws away the original last row of destination, and replaces it with a row that may have a different length than the other rows. An alternative, possibly neater, might look like this:
int[][] destination = new int[numFullRows + 1][];
for (int i = 0; i < numFullRows; ++i) {
    destination [i] = new int[numColumns];
}
destination [numFullRows] = new int [lengthLastRow];


Pivot 2D Array
Not totally sure that's how the 2D array is really arranged but it sounds cool.
In the example below a generator function (cycle()) is used to cycle through the "columns" (sub-arrays) of the given 2D array. If there's a sub-array that has reached it's capacity, the number will be added to the next sub-array that has room. Details are commented in the example.
Metrics
from JSHint (excluding log())
There are 4 functions in this file.
Function with the largest signature take 2 arguments, while the median is 1.
Largest function has 10 statements in it, while the median is 2.
The most complex function has a cyclomatic complexity value of 3 while the median is 1.5.
function *cycle(array) {
  let i = 0;
  while (true) {
    yield array[i % array.length];
    i++;
  }
}

function pivot(matrix) {
  const flat = matrix.slice(0).flat();
  const cols = matrix.map((_, i) => i); 
  const iter = cycle(cols);
  const result = matrix.map(s => []);
  for (const num of flat) {
    let idx = iter.next().value;
    while (result[idx].length === matrix[idx].length) {
      idx = iter.next().value;
    }
    result[idx].push(num);
  }
  return result;
}

Example


// For demonstration purposes
const log = data => console.log(JSON.stringify(data));

/**
 * This generates a sequence of values from a given array 
 * indefinitely.
 * @param {array} array - An array
 * @yield {any} - an element from the array
 */
function *cycle(array) {
  let i = 0;
  while (true) {
    yield array[i % array.length];
    i++;
  }
}

/**
 * This function will pivot the values of a 2D array.
 * @param {array} matrix - A 2D array
 * @return {array} - A 2D array 
 */
function pivot(matrix) {
  /* If matrix = [[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6]] */
  // Flatten matrix
  /* [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6] */
  const flat = matrix.slice(0).flat();
  // Get an array of matrix's indices
  /* [0, 1, 2] */
  const cols = matrix.map((_, i) => i); 
  // Create a generator that cycles through cols
  /* Each .next().value = 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0...♾️ */
  const iter = cycle(cols);
  // Create an empty 2D array
  /* [ [], [], [] ] */ 
  const result = matrix.map(s => []);
  // Iterate through flat array
  for (const num of flat) {
    // Get the next value of cols
    let idx = iter.next().value;
    /*
      If the new sub-array is as long as the
      corresponding sub-array in matrix...
    */
    while (result[idx].length === matrix[idx].length) {
      // get the next idx from the generator
      idx = iter.next().value;
    }
    /*
      Add the current number in flat array into the 
      current sub-array of the new array...
    */
    result[idx].push(num);
  }
  // Return the new 2D array. 
  return result;
}
 
const A = [[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6]];
const B = [[0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6]];
const C = [[0, 1, 2 , 3, 4], [5, 6], [7, 8, 9]];
const D = [[0, 1], [2, 3, 4, 5], [6, 7], [8], [9, 10, 11, 12]];

log(pivot(A));
log(pivot(B));
log(pivot(C));
log(pivot(D));




Here is a small method in Java, which performs the operation.
void change( int arr[][] ) {
   String numeros[] = Arrays.deepToString( arr ).replace( "[", "" ).replace( "]", "" ).split( ", " );
   int k = numeros.length - 1;

   for( int j = arr[ 0 ].length - 1; j >= 0; j -- ) {
      for( int i = arr.length - 1; i >= 0; i -- ) {
         if( arr[ i ].length - 1 >= j ) {
            arr[ i ][ j ] = Integer.parseInt( numeros[ k -- ] );
         }
      }
   }
   System.out.println( Arrays.deepToString( arr ) );
}

As you can see, first I convert the "2D" array to a single dimension (of String), then all that remains is to iterate in "reverse", verify that the current row has the minimum length, and assign the corresponding value.
If we don't want to use "integrated" methods of the system, and we agree to complicate ourselves...
int[][] change2( int arr[][] ) {

     // I only use these variables to make the code more readable
   int longMax = arr.length;
   int lastRow = arr.length - 1;
   int lastCol = arr[ 0 ].length - 1;

     // We create a new array to return
   int aux[][] = new int[ arr.length ][];
   for( int i = 0; i < copy.length; i ++ ) {
      aux[ i ] = new int[ arr[ i ].length ];
   }

     // the variables "iB" and "jB" are responsible for the iteration of the original array
     // "iA" y "jA" are responsible for the iteration of the target array

   int jB = arr[ lastRow ].length - 1, iB = lastRow;

   for( int jA = lastCol; jA >= 0; jA -- ) {
      for( int iA = lastRow; iA >= 0; iA -- ) {
         if( arr[ iA ].length >= longMax ) {
            aux[ iA ][ jA ] = arr[ iB ][ jB -- ];
            if( jB < 0 && iB > 0 ) {
               iB --;
               jB = arr[ iB ].length - 1;
            }
         }
      }
      longMax --;
   }
   return aux;
}

Despite the apparent complexity, we only have two iterators in the same block, both starting at the last item, one going down the columns and the other down the rows.
